# APIが古いと軽快なのはなぜですか？

Tags: android

Androidアプリ開発初心者です。
Android Studio 2.0で作成をしていて、今まで、実機テストを、android.4.1.2(API 16)で行ってきました。
特に問題もなく、スムーズに動いてくれていました。

ある程度できた後、 android.6.0.1(API 23) で実機テストをしてみました。
すると、動作はカクカクしてしまい、まともに動きません。
キー入力も反応が悪く、入力もできません。

API16では、HTCと、xperiaタブレットで試して、どちらも問題なし。
API23では、xperia xと、DIGNOで試して、どちらもNGでした。

どういった理由で上記状況になってしまうのか、全く分からず困っています。
どんな可能性があるのか、ご教授頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

不具合の出ている具体的な個所としては、Animationをしようした、動きで、特に他の動作・効果音等が重なった際NGとなる。
また、timer.scheduleを使用した画像に入れ替えも飛び飛びでコマ落ち状態です。
効果音は、SoundPoolを使用しています。

何かしらのヒントでもあれば助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

メインの文面抜粋

---

```
 //音楽の読み込み・設定
p = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.s_m_map01);
p.setLooping(true);//連続再生ON
p.setVolume(0.4f, 0.4f);

//効果音設定
sp = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
sound_id[0] = sp.load(this, R.raw.s_s_map00, 1);
sound_id[1] = sp.load(this, R.raw.s_s_map01, 1);
sound_id[2] = sp.load(this, R.raw.s_s_map02, 1);

//定期実行スタート(基本　0.175秒毎)
timer.schedule(anim, 0L, 175L);



// 0.175秒ごとに実行**********************************************************************
TimerTask anim = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (App.power == 0 && power_0 == true){
            power_0 = false;
         }else{
            power_0 = true;//パワーがなくなると、２回に１回の処理へ

            if (kyara_i_t != 0) {
                //移動アニメーション実行へor実行中--------------------
                hdl.post(new kyara_i_jikkou());//移動実行
                } else if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b1)).isPressed() || ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b2)).isPressed() || ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b3)).isPressed() || ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b4)).isPressed()) {
                //移動無実行で、キーが長押しされた場合---------------------
                if (input == 1) {
                    kyara_i_t = 1;
                    if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b1)).isPressed()) kyara_i = 1;
                    if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b2)).isPressed()) kyara_i = 2;
                    if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b3)).isPressed()) kyara_i = 3;
                    if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b4)).isPressed()) kyara_i = 4;
                    hdl.post(new kyara_i_jikkou());//移動実行
                }
            } else {
                //何もなされてなければ、足踏み実行----------------------
                hdl.post(new kyara_anim());//足踏み実行
                }
            }
        }
    };

// キャラクターのアニメーション実行（足踏み）**************************
    class kyara_anim implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            //キャラクター足踏み画像へ変更
            int i;
            kyara_anim++;
            if (kyara_anim == 5) kyara_anim = 1;
            if (kyara_anim == 4) i = 2;
            else i = kyara_anim;

            img_id = "kyara";
            img_file = "kyara_" + kyara_no + "_" + kyara_m + "_" + i;
            img_img(img_file, img_id);
        }
    }
```

以上、一部抜粋してみました。該当箇所になるかわかりませんが、
よろしくお願いします。
（初めて作ったandroidプログラムで汚いですが、よろしくお願いします。）

---

ご回答、大変ありがとうございます。参考になります。
早速頂いたプログラムに変更してみましたが、状況は改善できませんでした。

その他、ご教授頂いた件について、ご回答いたします。

img_imgについて

```
private void img_img(String img_file2, String img_id2) {
        //画像の変更　img(画像データ,どの名前？)*******************************************************************************************************
        String[] stArrayData = img_file2.split("\\.");
        int mon_id = getResources().getIdentifier(stArrayData[0], "drawable", getPackageName());//リソースの取得

        String[] stArrayData2 = img_id2.split("\\.");
        int mon_id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(stArrayData2[0], "id", getPackageName());//リソースの取得

        ((ImageView) findViewById(mon_id2)).setImageResource(mon_id);
    }
```

画像を切り替えるプログラムとなっています。

CPUモニターについて
　　Android6.0 = CPUは30％位です。
　　Android4.1 = CPUは1％位です。
　　大きな差があります。

GPUモニターについて
Android6.0 =
　　Swap Buffers が100～200msとふり切れています。
　　たまにMisc Time も10msを超えています。
　　画像を前もって読み込んでいないのが原因でしょうか？
Android4.1 =
　　表示してくれませんでした？？

その他メモリーについて
　　Android6.0 = CPUは250MB位です。
　　Android4.1 = CPUは120MB位です。
　　解像度の違いからでしょうか？
　　元々、数字が大きいのが気になります。
　　インストール時のファイルサイズは、30MB位です。

以上、お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

追記**************************************************************************
Android4.1で通常通り動くことから初期設定に何か問題あるのかなとも
考えたんですが、下記の「build.gradle」は関係ないでしょうか？

①クラス

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

②app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**********************************"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    // 追加
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                if (output.outputFile != null
                        && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                    // .apk名の付け替え newNameを必要に応じて変更すること
                    def versionName  =defaultConfig.versionName
                    def newName      ="vs_v${versionName}.apk"
                    output.outputFile=new File(output.outputFile.parent,newName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 問題を再現できるようなJavaプログラムやレイアウトファイルを質問に貼り付けてもますか？（一部でも大丈夫です）回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: 使い方が分からずすいません、本文に追記しました。見づらくなってしまいましたが、アドバイスのほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: タイトルはAPIは古いと軽快なのは…なのですが、中身は新しいバージョンだと何故カクカクなのか…って感じですのでタイトルを合うように変えてみたほうが良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

はっきりした原因は分からないですが、いくつか改善できそうです。
問題が解決できなかもしれませんがご参考までに。

**1.**
0.175秒毎に実行される処理の中で重たい処理をされているようです。`findViewById` の呼び出しと、kyara_animクラスとkyara_i_jikkouクラスのインスタンス生成は避けたほうが良いです。

次のプログラムはイメージですが、先に `findViewById`で見つけた`ImageView`と、kyara_animとkyara_i_jikkouをインスタンス変数に入れておき、animの中ではそちらを参照するのはどうでしょうか？

```
private Runnable kyara_i_jikkou_runnable;
private Runnable kyara_anim_runnable;

private ImageView map_b1;
private ImageView map_b2;
private ImageView map_b3;
private ImageView map_b4;

// 0.175秒ごとに実行**********************************************************************
TimerTask anim = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (App.power == 0 && power_0 == true) {
            power_0 = false;

        } else {
            power_0 = true;//パワーがなくなると、２回に１回の処理へ

            if (kyara_i_t != 0) {
                //移動アニメーション実行へor実行中--------------------
                hdl.post(kyara_i_jikkou_runnable);//移動実行
            } else if (map_b1.isPressed() || map_b2.isPressed() || map_b3.isPressed() || map_b4.isPressed()) {
                //移動無実行で、キーが長押しされた場合---------------------
                if (input == 1) {
                    kyara_i_t = 1;
                    if (map_b1.isPressed()) kyara_i = 1;
                    if (map_b2.isPressed()) kyara_i = 2;
                    if (map_b3.isPressed()) kyara_i = 3;
                    if (map_b4.isPressed()) kyara_i = 4;
                    hdl.post(kyara_i_jikkou);//移動実行
                }
            } else {
                //何もなされてなければ、足踏み実行----------------------
                hdl.post(kyara_anim_runnable);//足踏み実行
            }
        }
    }
};

//メソッド名は適当ですが、初期化処理としてみてください。
void init() {
    ...

    map_b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b1);
    map_b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b2);
    map_b3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b3);
    map_b4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_b4);

    kyara_i_jikkou_runnable = new kyara_i_jikkou();
    kyara_anim_runnable = new kyara_anim();

    ...
}
```

**2.**
`img_img`メソッドの中で頻繁に画像切り替えているので、次のように改善できそうです。

- もし画像のバイト数が大きければ小さくしてみる。
- 事前に画像のBitmapを読み込んでおいてそれで差し替える or LevelListDrawable を使うともしかするとキャッシュが効いて負荷がさがるかもしれません。

LevelListDrawable
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html
http://y-anz-m.blogspot.jp/2010/11/androidlevellistdrawable.html

**3.**
AndroidStudioでしたら、CPUモニターとGPUモニターが付いていますので、
そちらをみるとアニメーションが遅くなっている原因の手がかりになると思います。
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-cpu.html

Comment: 返信の仕方が分からず、本文に追記しました。（最初はご回答文面に追記してしまいましたが‥　どちらがよかったのか‥）　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 間違っているかもしれませんが Swap Buffers はGPUの処理待ち時間だったと思います。GPUに負荷がかかっていそうですので、画像が大きいとか、頻繁に画像を更新しているのが原因のように思います。回答の「2」を更新してみました。

Comment: 画像は412KB=48ps×48ps程度に小さなものです。事前の読み込みもしてみます。

Comment: （画像はgifファイルとなっています）

Comment: 412KBは大きいように思います。仮に50KBくらいの小さい画像に差し替えてみてはどうでしょう？ もしそれで改善すれば画像サイズが原因だと分かるので。

Comment: 事前に読み込むという意味ですが、初期化処理でBitmapとして画像を読み込んでおいて、setImageResource()ではなくsetImageBitmap()で画像を差し替えてみてはどうでしょうという意味でした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速50KB位の画像に切り替えてみましたが、状況は全く変わりませんでした。各モニターの％状況もほぼ同じになっております。いろいろすいません。

Comment: 画像サイズではありませんでしたか。負荷が掛かりそうな処理を削ってみたり、アニメーションの間隔を遅くしてみたり、レイアウトを単純にしてみたりなど、少しずつ機能を落としていって原因を探るなどされたほうが良いかもしれませんね。

Comment: 大変ありがとうございます。バージョンは関係ないようですので、少しずつ機能を減らして原因を探して見たいと思います。大変ありがとうございました。